# How to return just an integer json after API call for query of a database? node.js express and mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, rest

I'm very new to java script and don't quite understand how to use promises. I'm trying to query a mysql databse to return a count of the number of entrys matching a specific day passed in on the api call.

My get request looks like:

```
apiRouter.get('/summaries/count/sql/:date', (req,  res) => {
    res.json(RiskSummaryDAO.countSQLSummariesPerDate(req.params.date))
});
```

The countSQLSummariesPerDate function is

```
function countSQLSummariesPerDate(date) {
    return db.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OutputRiskLevel_view WHERE (LOWER(OutputRiskLevel_view.description) LIKE \'%sql%\' OR LOWER(OutputRiskLevel_view.title) LIKE \'%sql%\') AND DATE(OutputRiskLevel_view.date_indexed)=?;', [date]).then(({results}) => {
        return results;
});
```

The query promise is

```
exports.query = (query, params = []) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!connection) {
            connection = exports.getDatabaseConnection();
        }
        connection.query(query, params, (err, results, fields) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve({
                results: results,
                fields: fields
            })
        })
    });
};
```

The query works on mysql workbench so I'm assuming that it has to do with the api call so if anyone could explain how it should look I would greatly appreciate it.

When I run the express app and execute the api call it only returns a blank json block {}.